# Precision-Recall values of retrieved document

Tags: precision-recall

I'm learning precison and recall of documents and I'm having trouble understanding this particular question.

The table below shows the relevance of the top 6 results returned by two ranked
retrieval search engines denoted by A and B. '+' indicates relevant documents and '-' indicates non-relelevant documents.

[image]

Assuming that the total number of relevant documents in the collection was 4, compute precision-recall values for the two engines for the top 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6 results.

The solution given for search engine A was:

Precision:--100%--|--50%--|--33.3%--|--25%--|--40%--|--50%--| 
Recall   :------25%--|--25%--|--25%-----|--25%--|--50%--|--75%--|

The solution for B:

Precision: --|100%--|--100%--|--66.6%--|--50%--|--60%--|--50%--| 
Recall: ----|---25%---|--50%----|--50%-----|--50%--|--75%--|--75%--|

I know how to calculate for single documents and that Precsion = TP/(TP+FP) and Recall is TP/(TP+FN). I'm just not sure how some of the values above are calculated.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to memorize formulas, try to understand the concepts.

"Precision" is: What proportion of the results are correct? Hence, for both A and B, if you take the top result, it is correct. The precision is 100%.

"Recall" is: What proportion of the correct results are present? Hence, for both A and B, if you take the top result, you have one out of four correct values, so the recall is 25%.

Comment: The 2nd result for A is irrelevant and I'm guessing the precision values till the 4th one were divided by 2,3 and 4 respectively while the recall stayed the same. How were the 5th an 6th precision values gotten? I understand how their recalls were calculated as you've explained.

Comment: I've gotten how the 4th and 5th values were calculated. 2/5 as it's the second relevant and 3/6 as it's the third relevant.

Comment: @Gina . . . Good.  Remember the definitions.  This seems like a good example to think about.